# Изменение вида адреса -- htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Есть сайт `www.example.com`

Есть код в `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?q=$1
```

Добился желаемого результата(`www.example.com/query`). Как теперь допилить этот код чтобы, я мог отправлять дополнительные параметры - `www.example.com/query?name=foo&age=25`

Comment: а где вы думаете брать name и age ?

Comment: на главной странице - $_GET["q"], $_GET["name"], $_GET["age"]

Comment: :))) нет. в htaccess'е

Comment: А понял, вы хотите сохранить элементы query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто добавьте ключ QSA

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA]
```